# Why does my line indent?

Tags: indentation

Please see line 20 and 21:

[image]

My question is about how vim decides to auto-indent line 21, and how to adjust that behaviour.

When I took this screenshot I had `formatoptions=qrn1a` set, however I believe even without `a` set, if I format using `ggqG` or `gqip`, for example, the same thing happens.

I have many options set, pertaining to text formatting, and it's not clear to me which is doing that and why.

Comment: Often it is useful to narrow them down by disabling them all and systematically re-enabling. Could depend on the filetype of the buffer as well.

Comment: Also: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble The only point in that article that stands out to me is the accessibility issue, and fair enough. In this case a graphical representation of what was happening was helpful and relevant. In any case, is there a standard (text) format that represents hidden characters such as spaces? If I were to represent that picture in ASCII, how would you suggest doing it, exactly? I doubt for example that screen-reading software reads out 'space space space space space space'.

Comment: if you need more than just accessibility, you should read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557), which I did link to in the article. Standard? Probably not, though I would love to configure reading software to do that—anyone who codes with such software probably *has* to. You could always just pick a character and say "blah represents space"...

Comment: I had read that, and most of it doesn't apply to the image I posted. I didn't post code, the image is clear, the file size minimal, nobody would need to copy/paste it, etc. As I said, the only really compelling reason I could find was accessibility, and I suppose in case anyone uses this site with images disabled. I'm not trying to be difficult, I just take issue with any claim that what I did was inappropriate or should be discouraged. Contextually I think it made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out it was `cindent`.